# RTK Query not passing headers

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have an RTK Query api like below

```js
export const wireguardApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'wireguardApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: '/api/',
        prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
            const token = (getState()).auth.access?.token;
            if (token)
                headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
            return headers;
        },
    }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getAllServers: builder.query({
            query: () => `wg/servers/`,
        }),
        obtainRefreshToken: builder.mutation({
            query: (formData) => ({
                url: `auth/token/obtain/`,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: formData,
            }),
        }),
    }),
});
```

And call it on my page using

```js
const { data: servers, error, isLoading, refetch, isFetching } = useGetAllServersQuery();
```

Yet, when the page loads, executing the query, it doesn't pass the authorization header.  Why?

Comment: Have you logged `token` and `headers` in `prepareHeaders` to make sure that `token` is present and after the `set` call, it's also available in `headers`?

Comment: @phry yes, I confirmed that the token variable is being populated correctly.  However, it seems that headers shows as a blank object after calling `headers.set()`.

Comment: Hmm, that is just a [`Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) object though. Are you using some kind of fetch polyfill here?

Comment: @phry not to my knowledge.  Odder still is copy and pasting this (and changing only names), it works.  Maybe some kind of weird cache issue somewhere along the line.  Will be investigating.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue

The problem is that access token is unavailable when the query starts
Make sure that adding the token executes before making queries. (You can check the sequence in Redux DevTools)

[image: ScreenShot of ReduxDevTools]

Here addFromLocalStorage executes before starting the query

Earlier I was using react useEffect to dispatch the action. Then the query started before adding the token

What then I did was

```js
store.dispatch(addFromLocalStorage())
```

in main.js or index.js where you've rendered your App.

This makes sure that access token is added before executing any query in your React App.